# Cheat sheet documentation django python

Tags: python, django

Is there any Cheat Sheet or Document where I can see all the build-in modules, functions, commands etc in Django and or Python and where I will get an overview of ALL possible elements I could use. I am sure this is would be a big file/image etc , but it would be very helpful to know what commands I could use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run:

```
pydoc -p 8080
```

And go [here](http://localhost:8080).

Comment: You are the master! Thanks a billion!

Comment: Nice one. Here's the output from [`pydoc --help`](http://pastie.org/4389518), and here's the official [documentation on pydoc](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/pydoc.html).

Answer (score 2):

For django use [this](http://www.mercurytide.co.uk/media/whitepapers/django-cheat-sheet/django10-cheat-sheet.pdf).  It is a little out of date but still relevant.

For python I like [this](http://rgruet.free.fr/PQR26/PQR2.6.html) quick reference.

Answer (score 0):

- There is the [Global Module Index](http://docs.python.org/modindex.html)
  for Python.
- Here are some [build-in functions](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html)

Comment: This is for the Python core and has nothing to do with Pylons.

Comment: @michaelmior Who said anything about pylons?  The question is for Django and Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using django, a useful way of browsing the template tags, models and so on for your project is to enable admin docs. See [this post on how to enable admin docs](http://ircubic.net/2009/11/how-to-reenable-djangos-admin-docs.html).

Comment: Blerk.  As new to Django, how do I download them?  I don't seem to have it installed.

Comment: @Charles. I installed django on Windows using easy_install and they're installed. I haven't checked my ubuntu box so the admin-docs app might not be installed automatically on ubuntu. If you say what your OS, python and django versions are, maybe someone will be able to help.